# Issue in importing query result from mysql to existing hive table

Tags: sqoop

When I am trying to import a MySQL table into an existing hive table the below commands are working fine .
But when I am trying to use a query to import the result into the same hive table , it is asking for `--target-dir` and `--split-by` .
Is it mandatory to provide them while importing query results ?  why are these not required while importing directly from table

I am getting the below error -

> Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
>   Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
>   19/03/29 02:50:40 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.13.0
>   19/03/29 02:50:40 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
>   Must specify destination with --target-dir. 
>   Try --help for usage instructions.

Importing directly form table -

```sh
sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
--username retail_dba \
--password cloudera \
--m 2 \
--table departments \
--hive-import \
--hive-home "/user/hive/warehouse/" \
--hive-table sqoop_import.dep \
--hive-overwrite \
--outdir java_files \
```

Importing using a query -

```sh
sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
--username retail_dba \
--password cloudera \
--m 2 \
--query "select department_id,department_name from departments where \$CONDITIONS and department_id>2" \
--hive-import \
--hive-home "/user/hive/warehouse/" \
--hive-table sqoop_import.dep \
--hive-overwrite \
--outdir java_files \
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***1. target-dir***

By default, Sqoop will create a directory with the same name as the imported table inside your home directory on HDFS and import all data there. So when you import using `--query` the directory name is unknown and you need to explicitly specify it.

***2. split-by***

When performing parallel imports, Sqoop needs a criterion by which it can split the workload. Sqoop uses a splitting column to split the workload. By default, Sqoop will identify the primary key column (if present) in a table and use it as the splitting column, but by using query imports you must select a splitting column with `--split-by` (see [method](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/f4f9543010e6bacc8db938ab81c239c2273691ea/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/manager/SqlManager.java#L614-L622)).

Comment: Yes, it makes sense . Thank you so much for the explanation .